# QuickBooks Online SDK - Connection Issues yesterday and today

Tags: sdk, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

We have two users getting errors yesterday and today when querying the chart of accounts in QuickBooks Online using the QBSDK.

```
Unrecognized QuickBooks warning 901: Failure to parse string
```

Unfortunately I cannot repeat this on my QBO file but I am on a different cluster than these clients.

The IDN Forums are read only so I was not sure where to post this.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: One gateway appservers was down today.That could be the reason. Can you please try it again and let us know if it is working fine.
Thanks